# I need to change the port and run an authetication key through an scp command

Tags: linux, windows, scp

Hi I am trying to send a file to a linux server but the ssh connection is not port 22 and i need to pass an identity key through as well. Is there anyway i can change the port and use the -i in an scp command. Thanks!

scp -P 50022 -i C:\filepath\identity_key_file_name C:\file_path\file_name username@host:/home/user

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. One thing that you have incorrect is that there is not supposed to be a space between the `-P` and the port number.

Try:

```
scp -P50022 -i C:\filepath\identity_key_file_name C:\file_path\file_name username@host:/home/user
```